# Catch-phrase - "крылатая фраза"

Tags: фразеология

Если "сatch-phrase" - это крылатая фраза, то почему у нас она "крылатая", а у англичан - "пойманная", то есть добыча? Разный менталитет?

Comment: Vera, вот объясните мне глупому, что вы вкладываете в слово почему в вашем вопросе? Я всегда пасую от подобного. Ответ потому, что они говорят по-английски, а мы - по-русски, вас вряд ли устроит. А другого ничего на ум не приходит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее, не фраза становится добычей, а её "добычей" становятся те, кто её подхватывает, она "ловит" их внимание (to catch one's eye = to get one's attention). Т. е. буквально это "броская фраза". В словаре 'A Dictionary Of Catch Phrases' автор сослался на определение от одного из своих коллег: это фраза, которая вошла в моду и охотно употребляется в народе (A catch phrase is a phrase that has caught on, and pleases the populace; to catch on - войти в моду; завоевать популярность; привиться). Поэтому различие наименований у нас и у них происходит от акцента на разные части такого условного определения: у них акцент на быстром вхождении в язык, у нас - на широком распространении. Возможно, это и не связано с различиями в ментальности.

Comment: Да, интересное мнение.

Answer (score 0):

Менталитет очень разный (ещё в таких случаях говорят о национальном характере, его особенностях). Англичане - сугубо интровертированная (аутистическая, шизотимическая) нация, и мышление у них "интровертированное", аутистическое. Среди русских интровертов намного меньше, чем среди англичан. Да и английский и русский интроверты отличаются друг от друга, несут в своих характерах национальные особенности. Английский язык чётко структурирован, концептуален. В русском языке этого нет, он гораздо более свободный, "разболтанный" (не знаю, как правильнее сказать) и за счёт этого более богатый (так, по крайней мере, считается). А уж если два народа такие разные, и языки такие разные, то идиоматические выражения в этих двух языках - тем более.

Comment: Крылатые слова - это некая ценность: выразительный образ, оригинальная мысль. В русском языке крылатые слова в свободном полете, ими может пользоваться каждый, это всеобщее достояние.  А в английском языке их надо обязательно "поймать", сделать личной собственностью. О какой-то разнице национальных характеров это говорит?

Comment: Многие россияне более душевно открыты, теплы, реалистичны (не концептуальны), и даже более безалаберны, бесхозяйственны, чем англичане. Англичане же холодны или холодноваты душевно, индивидуалисты (мой дом - моя крепость), прагматики, большие любители порядка, собственники и даже скупердяи. Частная собственность  (вообще собственность)  для многих из них - очень важная (концептуально важная) вещь. Отношение к крылатым словам, вероятно, тоже вытекает из всех этих характеристик русских и англичан.

Answer (score 0):

Такие слова обычно быстроприникают в общество и быстро схватываются им. Отсюда и и такое название. Обратите внимание: Крылатые выражения можно перевести и дословно:wing-word.

Comment: Серж, но крылатые слова никто не переводит, весь смысл заключается в том, что одинаковое содержание (или одинаковые ситуации) передаются РАЗНЫМИ ОБРАЗАМИ и, соответственно, разными словами. И разная эмоциональная составляющая таких слов как раз и характеризует национальный характер.

Comment: Вера, я не имел перевод самих крылатых слов, выражение "крылатые слова" можно перевести с помощью кальки - wing-word.

Comment: Вера, а  насчет перевода ошибаетесь. Все зависит от той или иной фразы, если фраза подается переводу - ее можно перевести.

Answer (score -1):

Сборники крылатых фраз и афоризмов появились с середины 1960-х. К тому времени вовсю бытовали *Крылья Родины*, *крылатое племя героев*, *Крылья Советов* как некая эмоционально-идеологическая марка подъёмной силы восстановления могущества огромной страны. Но слова — не зная эпохи, их невозможно понять и классифицировать — были и прежде крылатыми.

Из записей В.Д. Набокова от июля 1918 г.: «В особенности возмущался он Италией и теми "аннексиями" (тогда ещё это слово не стало крылатым), которые она себе выговорила».